# How can i display the ftp files content and directories to look like the ftp content on the server?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This method does work and does adding the files to the listBox.
But some of the files are directories and i wonder if there is a way to display the directories witha directory symbol this yellow directory near it ?

```
public void getFtpFileList()
{
    List<string> files = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://"+ txtHost.Text) as FtpWebRequest;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        FtpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            files.Add(reader.ReadLine());
        }
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(file);
        }
        reader.Close();
        responseStream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

This is a screenshot on the top left is my program and under it it's my ftp.
I want somehow to display on the listBox as much as close the way it look like in my ftp server.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I don't think you can do that with a ListBox. Search for ListView or GridView in WinForms instead.

Comment: you can write your code in DrawItem event to draw the icons.